# Is the following expression is clear: "determines whether A is greater than or equal to B"?

Tags: conjunctions, comparison, terminology

> The processor determines whether value X ≧ 100.

I am trying to rewrite the above sentence without using the mathematical symbol. My example is as follows:

> The processor determines whether value X is greater than or equal to
>   100.

I am afraid that this may be misinterpreted as follows:

> The processor determines whether value X is greater than 100 or value
>   X is equal to 100.

Is there a possibility of such misinterpretation?

Comment: I'd say yes. To avoid ambiguity, I think you could rephrase this as:**The processor determines whether value X *might be** equal to or greater than 100.** I prefer putting **equal to** before **greater than** as a natural order of progression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a possibility of misinterpretation. In conversational English, it would likely be clear what you meant, but in a technical specification, it's critical that your intent be unambiguous.

I think this situation might be one in which the mathematical symbol is actually clearer than the equivalent English, but I would suggest the following if you absolutely need to make this change:

> The processor determines **whether or not** value X is greater than or equal to 100.
>
> The processor determines whether value X is **less than** 100.

Comment: I want to use the phrase "greater than or equal to", so I will adopt your first sentence.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is ambiguous. There are other phrases that more clearly express "greater than or equal". For instance, you can say "at least". In some contexts, "has reached" works. Also, "The processor determines whether value X is greater than or equal to 100.", in the sense you mean, is logically equivalent to "The processor determines whether value X is less than 100."

Comment: @godel9, Yes, that's what I meant to say.

Comment: In that case, I withdraw my comment. :-)